# info re: add/remove methods in stringLists

Tags: c#

The current code is compiling O.K at the moment and if a duplicate is found it is automatically removed. is there anyway the user can chose if they would like to keep the duplicate before removing. Or is there another method i can look at that would be suitable.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> dictionaryList = new List<string>();
        string input;

        Console.Write("Please enter a string or END to finish: ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        while (input.ToUpper() != "END")
        {
            if (!dictionaryList.Contains(input)) // This is where i am looking of a user response of y/n too add duplicate string

            dictionaryList.Add(input);

            Console.Write("Please enter a string or END to finish: ");
            input = Console.ReadLine();

        }

        dictionaryList.Sort();
        Console.WriteLine("Dictionary Contents:");
        foreach (string wordList in dictionaryList)
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + wordList);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If there is likely to be many duplicates then a Dictionary<string, int> may suit better, where int is the number of times the string/word occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following code:

```
            List<string> dictionaryList = new List<string>();

            string input;

            Console.Write("Please enter a string or END to finish: ");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            while (input.ToUpper() != "END")
            {
                if (dictionaryList.Contains(input))
                {
                    Console.Write("Do you want to have dup string(Y/N):");
                    string response = string.Empty;
                    response = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (response.ToUpper().Equals("Y"))
                        dictionaryList.Add(input);    
                }
                else
                {
                    dictionaryList.Add(input);
                }
                Console.Write("Please enter a string or END to finish: ");
                input = Console.ReadLine();

            }

            dictionaryList.Sort();
            Console.WriteLine("Dictionary Contents:");
            foreach (string wordList in dictionaryList)
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + wordList);
```

Comment: I was testing the code but if response for Console.Write("Do you want to have dup string(Y/N):"); is 'n' it will delete that string altogether i.e
{
input

one
two
three
one (response 'n')
four
five
six
end

output

two
three
four
five
six
}

Comment: I thought you would like to remove all items which have input string if the user is not willing to keep dup string......

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Its only if the user enters word again 'by mistake' it will prompt user to confirm if they would like it to appear twice or only the first entry.

Comment: perfect, so just delete the remove. (atIndex) to ensure only 1 entry removed not all. Thankyou.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
while (input.ToUpper() != "END")
{
    bool blnAdd = true;
    if (dictionaryList.Contains(input))
    {
        Console.Write("Already exists, keep the duplicate? (Y/N)");
        blnAdd = Console.ReadLine().Equals("Y");
    }

    if (blnAdd)
        dictionaryList.Add(input);

    Console.Write("Please enter a string or END to finish: ");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Logic behind the code: if the input already exists in the list, alert the user and read his answer - only if `Y` add the item.